# What happens if a positive and negative wire touches while connected to a speaker?

Tags: audio, wiring, bad-wiring

Would it just give feedback? Or have negative effects on the speaker itself?

Comment: You short the speaker out, possibly damaging the amplifier.

Comment: Ok, another question: What if the positive and negative wires inside an aux cable were touching and then you connected that to your car stereo

Comment: Probably nothing since the AUX connection in your car is an input.

Comment: No feedback,  no negative effect on the speaker.   This is assuming the negative and positive you mention are from the output of an audio amplifier.  Not good for the amplifier which should have short protection.

Comment: There's basically a constant tone when I plug in the aux cable.

Comment: The beep is not due to the speaker.  So by constant beep I assume is a continuous somewhat high pitch tone.  I do not want to jump to the amp was damaged, that's not that likely.  It could be a poor connection on one of the cables.  The reason I don't think anything was damaged because no one in there right mind would sell a product that would easily cause field failures which causes customer support and return authorization headaches and expense.

Comment: Poor connection on the cable seems likely as I had to solder it at a bad angle. You are correct about it being somewhat high pitched and continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speaker will see 0V, and will therefore be silent. In most cases, it won't have negative effects on the speaker. It is possible to cause damage to certain vulnerable drivers if the short occurs at the peak of a signal and causes a fast transient that's large enough to cause overexcursion (mechanical damage to the voice coil, spider, or cone can occur). However, this is not likely, particularly with smaller drivers.

However, the amplifier will be very unhappy with a short. Whether or not the amplifier fails is dependent on the specifics of the amplifier design: a well-built amplifier will detect the short and go into protection/limiting, while a poorly built amplifier will fail, likely due to overcurrent on the main output transistors or perhaps a power supply failure. It depends.